# integrate moments normal distribution between finite limits

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Can somebody help me to evaluate the following integral: 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_a^b x^2 \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\mathrm dx$$

Answer involving cumulative normal (erf) would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Would an answer involving the Erf function be acceptable?

Comment: try out wolframalpha; that suffices at least if 'erf' is acceptable. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28x^2*exp%28-x^2%29%2C{x%2C0%2Ct}%29

Comment: somehow the link is garbled above; but I guess you get the point!

Comment: hi the link you gave me wasn't able to do this integral

Comment: which part of this q is about research level mathematics?

Comment: Define $F(t) = \int_0^t x^2 e^{-x^2} dx$. Do some variable subs, ask yourself what is $F(b)-F(a)$, use the wolframalpha link, etc., ...

Answer (score 1):

The change of variable $x=t\sigma\sqrt2$ shows that the integral $I$ to be computed is
$$
I=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt\pi}J\left(\frac{a}{\sigma\sqrt2},\frac{b}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right),\qquad J(x,y)=\int_x^y2t^2\mathrm e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt.
$$
By an integration by parts using the functions $u(t)=-t$ and $v(t)=\mathrm e^{-t^2}$,
$$
J(x,y)=\left.-t\mathrm e^{-t^2}\right|_x^y+\int_x^y\mathrm e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt=x\mathrm e^{-x^2}-y\mathrm e^{-y^2}+\frac12\sqrt{\pi}(\mathrm{erf}(y)-\mathrm{erf}(x)).
$$
Thus, the value of the integral to be computed is
$$
I=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(a\mathrm e^{-a^2/(2\sigma^2)}-b\mathrm e^{-b^2/(2\sigma^2)}\right)+\frac12\sigma^2\left(\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right)-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right)\right).
$$